# How can i make lib file on reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a global function.
For example, create a `Javascript` file with

```
function increment (val) {
  return val + 1;
}
```

And I want to use this function in `app.js` or some other component.
How do I set up this structure in `ReactJS`?

Answer (score 1):

Just `export` your function as a module and `import` it in `app.js`

```
export function increment (val) {
  return val + 1;
}
```

Then in your `app.js`:

```
import { increment } from 'your_module_path';
//...
    let b = increment(1);
```